# Unnecessary Steps in A Proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, group-isomorphism

> Let $D_{2n} = \langle r,s ~|~ r^n = s^2 = 1, ~ rs = sr^{-1} \rangle$ be the usual presentation of the dihedral group of order $2n$ and let $k$ be a positive integer dividing $n$. Prove that $D_{2n}/\langle r^k \rangle \simeq D_{2k}$.

See [link_1](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/subgroups-generated-by-powers-of-r-are-normal-in-dih2n/) and [link_2](http://faculty.missouri.edu/~chindrisc/docs/HWK2-Algebra-I-2013.pdf).

With respect to link_1, is that solution more complicated than needed? Why not simply note that $|D_{2n}/\langle r^k \rangle | = 2k$, define $\varphi(s^a r^b) = s^a r^b \langle r^k \rangle$, verifying that it is a homomorphism, and then simply note that it is surjective because $s^a r^b \langle r^k \rangle = \varphi (s^a r^b)$, as the author does in the last line? Since we are dealing with a map between finite sets of the same cardinality, it immediately follows $\varphi$ is also injective.

Now with respect to link_2, if they are following Dummit and Foote as I am, and it appears they are, I don't see how the hint would be helpful. According to what I have learned so far in DF, showing that the two generators satisfy the same relations would not suffice to show they are isomorphic (unless I am overlooking something). So, my question is, am I overlooking something in DF, and if not what is the theorem that would guarantee that there would be an isomorpism based on the fact that their generators satisfy the same relations? In short, what would the statement of this theorem be?

**EDIT**

Here I will show that $\varphi : D_{2k} \rightarrow D_{2n}/\langle r^k \rangle$ as defined above is well-defined. Suppose that $s^a r^b = s^c r^d$ , where these are taken to be arbitrary elements in $D_{2k}$. Now, if either of $a$ or $c$ is zero and not the other, then we have a contradiction, since $s \neq r^z$ for any integer $z$; hence, either $a=c=0$ or $a=c=1$. In either case, the equation reduces to $r^b = r^d$, implying that $b = k \ell + d$. Thus, $\varphi (r^b) = \varphi r^{k \ell + d} = r^{k \ell + d} \langle r^k \rangle = r^d \langle r^k \rangle = \varphi (r^d)$, thereby proving that $\varphi$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in your way we don't know to which group we're mapping $D_{2n}$. We only know that it's a group of order $2k$, which isn't enough. Hence we need to prove that the group is generated by two elements, namely $\phi(r)$ and $\phi(s)$ and also we need to check that they satisfy the relation $\phi(r)\phi(s) = \phi(s)\phi(r)^{-1}$. This uniquely determines $D_{2k}$

Regarding your second question I this is because in some cases two generators and one relation on them isn't enough to uniquely determine the group. So there are more than one possibility, so we can't guarantee the isomorphism of the groups. But when it comes to the relation $\langle r,s | r^n = s^2 = 1; rs=sr^{-1}\rangle$ it uniquely determines a group.

Comment: Well, I am taking $\varphi$ to be a map from $D_{2k}$ to $D_{2n}/\langle r^k \rangle$.

Comment: @user193319 Then you need to prove that $\phi$ is an isomorphism, which isn't that easy to be fair. In fact the hard part is proving that $\phi$ is well-defined, as for example $rs$ can be also expressed as $sr^{-1}$, which again boils down to proving that $\phi(g)$ and $\phi(s)$ are generators of $D_{2n}/ \langle r^k \rangle$ and they satsify the relation.

Comment: Okay. I added to my OP a proof that the map is well-defined. It didn't seem too difficult; and in fact still seems simpler, but perhaps I made an error along the way.

Comment: @user193319 I would recommend you to proceed with proving that $\phi$ is homomorphism. We need to show that $\phi(s^ar^bs^cr^d) = \phi(s^ar^b)\phi(s^cs^d)$, which might be harder than you expect. Please note that we don't know any relation on $\phi(r)$ and $\phi(s)$.

Comment: Would this prove it? $\phi(s^ar^bs^cr^d) = \phi (s^a s^c r^{-b} r^d) = \phi (s^{a+c} r^{-b+d}) =  s^{a+c} r^{-b+d} \langle r^k \rangle = s^a s^c r^{-b} r^d \langle r^k \rangle = s^a r^b s^c r^d \langle r^k \rangle = s^a r^b \langle r^k \rangle \cdot s^c r^d \langle r^k \rangle  = \phi(s^ar^b)\phi(s^cs^d)$

Comment: @user193319 The problem is with this line $s^as^cr^{-b}r^d\langle r^k \rangle = s^ar^bs^cr^d \langle r^k \rangle$. This is because the we don't know that the relation $r\langle r^k \rangle s\langle r^k \rangle = s\langle r^k \rangle r^{-1}\langle r^k \rangle$ is satisfied in $D_{2n}/\langle r^k \rangle$.

Comment: @user193319 Actually to avoid confusion it would be better to map $\phi(s^tr^q)$ to $a^tb^q \langle r^k \rangle$, where $a\langle r^k \rangle, b\langle r^k \rangle$ are generators of $\phi$

Comment: I don't see how that is a problem. $s^as^cr^{-b}r^d$ is an element in $D_{2n}$ and the relation $s^as^cr^{-b}r^d = s^as^cr^{-b}r^d\langle r^k$ holds in $D_{2n}$, so I am merely substituting this in. As far as I see it, I am not appealing to any relations in $D_{2n}/ \langle r^k \rangle$, but rather in $D_{2n}$

Comment: Sure, using $a$ and $b$ might be clearer, but they would still be elements in $D_{2n}$.

Comment: @user193319 The thing is that you don't do much stuffs differently than the author in the proof, so I can't see how you're improving the solution. You need to prove that the mapping is well-defined, which the author does in the linked lemma and then you need to prove that the mapping is homomorphism and that it's isomoprhism in fact, which the author does in the first part of proof. The best improvement I could see is collecting the first three paragraphs in one line.